# Alternatives to the Dynamic Time Warping (DTW) method

Tags: c#, time-series

I am doing some research into methods of comparing time series data. One of the algorithms that I have found being used for matching this type of data is the DTW (Dynamic Time Warping) algorithm.

The data I have, resemble the following structure (this can be one path):

```
Path    Event      Time            Location (x,y)
  1       1       2:30:02             1,5
  1       2       2:30:04             2,7
  1       3       2:30:06             4,4
...
...
```

Now, I was wondering whether there are other algorithms that would be suitable to find the closest match for the given path.

Comment: You need to provide more information here.  What logic is deciding a "match"?  If I use the case of gesture recognition and the example of a path such as drawing the number '6' then is a match required based on the shape of the path (ie: a big 6 should 'match' a small '6' - scaling only), the topology of the path (ie : lowercase greek 'sigma' matches '6' matches 'b', etc), the speed of the path (ie: a quickly drawn 6 does not match a slowly drawn one) - what are you trying to accomplish?  To what accuracy?  With what weights?  A problem like this needs more parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If two paths are the same length, say *n*, then they are really points in an *2n*-dimensional space.  The first location determines the first two dimensions, the second location determines the next two dimensions, and so on.  For example, if we just take the three points in your example, the path can be represented as the single 6-dimensional point (1, 5, 2, 7, 4, 4).  If we want to compare this to another three-point path, we can compute either the Euclidean distance (square root of the sum of squares of per-dimension distances between the two points) or the Manhattan distance (sum of the per-dimension differences).

For example, the boring path that stays at (0, 0) for all three times becomes the 6-dimensional point (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0).  Then the Euclidean distance between this point and your example path is `sqrt((1-0)^2 + (5-0)^2 + (2-0)^2 + (7-0)^2 + (4-0)^2 + (4-0)^2) = sqrt(111) = 10.54`.  The Manhattan distance is `abs(1-0) + abs(5-0) + abs(2-0) + abs(7-0) + abs(4-0) + abs(4-0) = 23`.  This kind of a difference between the metrics is not unusual, since the Manhattan distance is provably at least as great as the Euclidean distance.

Of course one problem with this approach is that not all paths will be of the same length.  However, you can easily cut off the longer path to the same length as the shorter path, or consider the shorter of the two paths to stay at the same location or moving in the same direction after measurements end, until both paths are the same length.  Either approach will introduce some inaccuracies, but no matter what you do you have to deal with the fact that you are missing data on the short path and have to make up for it somehow.

**EDIT:**

Assuming that `path1` and `path2` are both `List<Tuple<int, int>>` objects containing the points, we can cut off the longer list to match the shorter list as:

```
// Enumerable.Zip stops when it finishes one of the sequences
List<Tuple<int, int, int, int>> matchingPoints = Enumerable.Zip(path1, path2,
    (tupl1, tupl2) =>
        Tuple.Create(tupl1.Item1, tupl1.Item2, tupl2.Item1, tupl2.Item2));
```

Then, you can use the following code to find the Manhattan distance:

```
int manhattanDistance = matchingPoints
    .Sum(tupl => Math.Abs(tupl.Item1 - tupl.Item3)
               + Math.Abs(tupl.Item2 - tupl.Item4));
```

With the same assumptions as for the Manhattan distance, we can generate the Euclidean distance as:

```
int euclideanDistanceSquared = matchingPoints
    .Sum(tupl => Math.Pow(tupl.Item1 - tupl.Item3, 2)
               + Math.Pow(tupl.Item2 - tupl.Item4, 2));
double euclideanDistance = Math.Sqrt(euclideanDistanceSquared);
```

Comment: I had this idea as well, but I could not apply it, mostly due to the fact that paths are never equal (some paths can be 10x the length of other paths) therefore a windowing function would be time consuming.

Comment: Not necessarily.  As I mentioned above, you could cut off the longer path to match the length of the shorter path, and then simply compute the distance from there.  No need for a windowing function.

Comment: Does this consider the order of points? If I walk PATH A in one direction, it should not match the same path in the other direction (returning)

Comment: This does consider the order of points, since the Enumerable.Zip call (used to create matchingPoints) matches up the first point of path1 with the first point of path2, the second point of path1 with the second point of path2, and so on.

Comment: I tested that, sorry for the late reply. It does work correctly. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The keyword you are looking for is "(dis-)similarity measures".

Euclidean Distance (ED) as referred to by Adam Mihalcin (first answer) is easily computable and somehow reflects the natural understanding of the word distance in natural language. Yet when comparing two time series, DTW is to be preffered - especially when applied to real world data.

1) ED can only be applied to series of equal length. Therefore when points are missing, ED simply is not computable (unless also cutting the other sequence, thus loosing more information).

2) ED does not allow time-shifting or time-warping opposed to all algorithms which are based on DTW.

Thus ED is not a real alternative to DTW, because the requirements and restrictions are much higher. But to answer your question, I want to recommend to you this lecture:

Time-series clustering – A decade review
Saeed Aghabozorgi, Ali Seyed Shirkhorshidi, Teh Ying Wah
http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0306437915000733

This paper gives an overview about (dis-)similarity measures used in time series clustering. Here a little excerpt to motivate your actually reading the paper:

[image]

Comment: This answer doesn't answer the actual question but it works perfectly as a reaction to the accepted answer. You are completely right, ED is not at all any alternative to DTW. Many thanks, +1 for explanation.

Answer (score 2):

There's another question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8917973/geospatial-routing) that might be of some help. If you already have a given path, you can find the closest match by using the cross-track distance algorithm; on the other hand, if you actually want to solve the pattern-recognition problem, you might want to find out more about Levenshtein distance and Elastic Matching (from Wikipedia: "Elastic matching can be defined as an optimization problem of two-dimensional warping specifying corresponding pixels between subjected images".